# Passport for layover in Paris waiting for connection flight to The Netherlands

Tags: passports, eu, connecting-flights, south-african-citizens

We are flying back to The Netherlands, where I work, and have to transfer via Paris. However, we came to South Africa to renew the kids passports which expire 25 March 2019. Their passports are not yet ready at SA Home Affairs, although we were told it would only take 10 working days.

Our flight back is tonight at 20:00. I have to start work again on the 14th March and the kids have to start school on the same day. We will be waiting inside the Paris airport for our connecting flight to The Netherlands. Can there be an exception to the rule regarding the expiration date of the kids passports?

Comment: What rule do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents, states in relevant part:

> Passport required.
>
> - Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to residents of Netherlands must be valid on arrival.
>
> Warning:
>
> - Passports and other travel documents accepted for entry are considered valid until the day before the expiration date.

This means that if your passport expiry date is 25 March, you must enter the Netherlands on or before 24 March.